# Python PIL error JPEG, JPG file : encoder error -2 when writing image file

Tags: linux, python-imaging-library, jpeg, redhat, python-3.8

I am using python 3.8.10 and PIL version 9.0.1. My application runs in both windows and linux (red-hat).
I have to resize, crop and save image in new path. PNG, GIF image works fine but JPG and JPEG images not working in linux.
All above mentioned image format works fine in windows

Below is the code, which I use to open and resize image,

```py
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("jpeg/file/path")
width, height = img.size
resize_img = img.resize((width-1, height-1))
```

This code works fine in windows. But, in linux, on resize() function being called, it throws error, "**broken data stream when reading image file**"

In internet, to solve above issue, following code is recommended to be executed before opening file. I have added it. But, even without adding below code, it works fine in windows.

```py
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Further, I need to save resized image. I did using below code.

```py
resize_img.save("/path/to/new/image")
```

But, it throws error "**encoder error -2 when writing image file**"

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: PIL uses lazy loading, so it doesn't read the whole file when you open it.  It waits until you perform an operation that requires the image data, like the `resize`.

Comment: You might have a corrupt installation on Linux, you could try removing and re-installing it.

Comment: Does it fail on every JPEG or just some JPEGs? Try saving each file you process just as a raw, binary file before you start processing it - then you can check them later with proper tools. Try storing the filename of your output file in a variable, then printing that variable to `stderr` (so it gets flushed) before saving and then use that exact same variable in your `resize_image.save(VARIABLE)` command.

Comment: @MarkRansom Installation is not corrupt

Comment: @MarkSetchell It happens with all jpg, jpeg images. I have saved output path in variable, flushed the variable to stderr using print and used the exact variable for save(). I get 2nd error, "encoder error -2 when writing image file"

Comment: Hmmm... try printing first 20 bytes and last 20 bytes of each JPEG before opening with PIL.

Comment: And how did you verify your installation is not corrupt?  Forgive me if I don't believe you.

Comment: @MarkRansom During my application installation, along with the application, we install separate python and other packages (like PIL inside site-packages directory) for python inside installation folder itself. This ensures python version and other packages version used by the application are intended version. We don't use python installed in the system

Comment: @MarkSetchell What data should i check or interpret from first 20 and last 20 bytes of JPEG file ?

Comment: The first 3 bytes are a *"magic"* number which should be `ff d8 ff` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG and the last few bytes should be `ff d9` see https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/ Together they give a good idea if your JPEGs are valid and not truncated.